# How to build a MeteorJs application server-side only?

Tags: meteor

i'm refactoring an application build when meteor was in 0.5.x
I need to scale the application, so i will now have different applications able to run on different core. One of them will be dedicated to web-application, but others are server only. For those case i don't want Meteor to serve anything, it must not be an http server.

I tried to configure differently the package list (file .meteor/packages:

```
# standard package of meteor-platform in server app only
application-configuration
autoupdate
base64
binary-heap
callback-hook
check
ddp
deps
ejson
follower-livedata
geojson-utils
id-map
json
logging
meteor
mongo
observe-sequence
ordered-dict
random
retry
routepolicy

# standard package of meteor-platform in client app
#blaze
#blaze-tools
#boilerplate-generator
#html-tools
#htmljs
#jquery
#minifiers
#minimongo
#reactive-var
#spacebars
#spacebars-compiler
#templating
#tracker
#ui
#webapp
#webapp-hashing

# specific app package
```

But when i run #> meteor
Then it tells me that the server is listening, so it doesn't work

I also tried to remove "browser platform" :

```
meteor remove-platform browser
```

but it tells me that it cannot remove platform in this version of meteor

Where am i wrong ? the list of packages is not the right one for a server only application ?

Comment: Please explain more what you mean "it must not be an http server". Meteor, as a web framework, is inherently http. What you say sounds like asking "How can I have apache not be http?"

Comment: You you still want your Meteor app to be able to accept DDP connections? Or only access the database?

Comment: NodeJs is a language on which you can build web app / command app / ...
Meteor rely on Node, so i expect to build an application that does not serve http response. Imagine i want to spy a folder on a server, and read file content and store them in a MongoDB. I don't need Http server. 
I use MeteorJs because i like it's APIs and it allows me to do a lot of thing easily. So in my case i don't need DDP, just Mongo Collection a few other things.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible at the moment, "maybe in a future version" [as someone from MDG says](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6091#issuecomment-175424043)

Answer (score -3):

Meteor relies on the DDP package to listen to incoming requests and DDP listens on websockets, which is basically http.

Therefore it has to listen for something on some port. If it does not listen, you cannot tell the app to do anything or ask it for anything so then, what use is it?

But if you don't want your app to interfere with your other apps in tems of the ports it binds to, then give it a custom port when you are starting it.

```
$ meteor run --port 12345
```

Comment: Meteor rely on NodeJS and MongoDb (actually), DDP is just one component of the Framework, but you are not oblige to use it because a lot of packages in the framework doesn't rely on DDP : Collection on Server just spy opLog (or polling) for example...
So it should be possible to start MeteorJS without Http Server (like NodeJs does)

Comment: Theoretically, you are correct. But there are packages that, when omitted, renders the whole of Meteor useless. Take `underscore` for example, you simply cannot remove it, although it is just like any other package. DDP is what gets other systems talk to Meteor. If nothing can talk to Meteor, than it just becomes self contained, something like `cron`. Therefore, I completely disagree with your remark. DDP is a core package which should and can not be removed.

Comment: Ah, I just read your other comment in your original post. Hmm... Interesting idea, but I would not recommend it. Meteor is good at reactivity data everywhere, live templating etc. For a task like watching file content and inserting data in mongodb, node will be much much easier. Meteor does not seem to provide much value there. Unless you can provide more specific arguments about the task you got.

Comment: So i can imagine two processes : on looking for file from one folder, and in that case, yes pure node would be enough. But if i do the opposite : observe added item in collection and writing file, sending mail, calling web service for each document added, in that case, Meteor provide all i need, and http server is useless (hope it helps to understand).

Comment: That makes more sense, yes. But still, there are a lot of node based lightweight alternatives to that. Even pure mongo based (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) alternatives exist to get a stream out of mongo, attach event handlers, write files, make http requests etc. Yes meteor indeed does all those things, and rather easily, but let's be honest, it is not where it excels at. But yes, you can use anything to do anything. By way of deduction, a great web app can be written in pure assembly, but we don't do that. We don't take ddp away from meteor either :)